# Integer to number roman with macros

Tags: c, macros

I have the following code that converts a number to number roman

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void roman(char *s, unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        fputs("Roman numeral zero does not exist ", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

#define digit(loop, num, c) \
      loop (n >= num)         \
         {*(s++) = c;         \
          n -= num;}
#define digits(loop, num, c1, c2) \
      loop (n >= num)               \
         {*(s++) = c1;              \
          *(s++) = c2;              \
          n -= num;}

    digit  ( while, 1000, 'M'      )
    digits ( if,     900, 'C', 'M' )
    digit  ( if,     500, 'D'      )
    digits ( if,     400, 'C', 'D' )
    digit  ( while,  100, 'C'      )
    digits ( if,      90, 'X', 'C' )
    digit  ( if,      50, 'L'      )
    digits ( if,      40, 'X', 'L' )
    digit  ( while,   10, 'X'      )
    digits ( if,       9, 'I', 'X' )
    digit  ( if,       5, 'V'      )
    digits ( if,       4, 'I', 'V' )
    digit  ( while,    1, 'I'      )

#undef digit
#undef digits

    *s = 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[16];
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
    {
        roman(buffer, i);
        printf("%4u: %s\n", i, buffer);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The trouble is I'm thinking in a version without macros but I find no feasible way to do without extending the code

someone has any idea to do this?

Comment: I'm just... stunned by this.

Comment: The way you're doing it with macros is not very readable, nor maintainable. Implement the logic explicitly without the macros. You can implement a recursive variant. If the number is in the thousands, the result is `"M ... M" + roman(n % 1000)` for instance (You'd do the concatenation in C-esque way, or you'd pass `s + m_count` as the pointer to the second call). That makes it a bit easier.

Comment: @Martin James what do you mean

Comment: This is actually a question for code review, not SO, as the code seems to work as expected (otherwise, please state what problem you have and where it occurs.

Comment: @Mohammad Ali Baydoun What would that be like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you are implementing a table based integer to roman numbers system. You just happen to be implementing the table in code rather than in data.

Here's what it would look like if we encoded the conversions in an array. We can also simplify the logic by turning every `if` statement in your code above, into a `while` statement.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static struct {
    unsigned decimal;
    char *roman;
} conversion_table[] = {
    {1000, "M" },
    { 900, "CM"},
    { 500, "D" },
    { 400, "CD"},
    { 100, "C" },
    {  90, "XC"},
    {  50, "L" },
    {  40, "XL"},
    {  10, "X" },
    {   9, "IX"},
    {   5, "V" },
    {   4, "IV"},
    {   1, "I" },
};

void roman(char *s, unsigned int n) {
    s[0] = '\0';

    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(conversion_table) / sizeof(*conversion_table); ++i) {
        while (n >= conversion_table[i].decimal) {
            n -= conversion_table[i].decimal;
            strcat(s, conversion_table[i].roman);
            s += strlen(s);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char s[100];

    roman(s, 1024);
    printf("%d == %s\n", 1024, s);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
1024 == MXXIV
```

Comment: Upvoted, but found it odd that you would `strcat` when you're updating the pointer anyways (`strcpy` would work).

Comment: @Bill Lynch excellent work, just one thing what does this line s += strlen(s); It is equivalent to *(s + strlen(s)); or am I wrong.